# Parsing an array sent from database

Tags: php, html, arrays

Hello I am wondering how I would attempt to parse the data I retrieved from the database:

```
[
   {
      "q_id":"1",
      "type":"for",
      "author":"kappa420",
      "question":"what is the meaning of life?",
      "answer":"good question."
   },
   {
      "q_id":"2",
      "type":"recursive",
      "author":"kappa420",
      "question":"If only you knew",
      "answer":"That I was right behind you!"
   },
   {
      "q_id":"3",
      "type":"while",
      "author":"kappa420",
      "question":"who are you?",
      "answer":"ha-HA!"
   },
   {
      "q_id":"5",
      "type":"testtyte",
      "author":"testauthor",
      "question":"testquestion",
      "answer":""
   },
   {
      "q_id":"6",
      "type":"testtyte",
      "author":"testauthor",
      "question":"testquestion",
      "answer":"testanswer"
   },
   {
      "q_id":"7",
      "type":"public int add( int num1,",
      "author":"",
      "question":"Given two numbers the user must be able to add these numbers. ",
      "answer":" add(5,4) = 9\r\n add(2,3) = 5"
   },
   {
      "q_id":"8",
      "type":"public int add( int num1,",
      "author":"",
      "question":"Given two numbers the user must be able to add these numbers. ",
      "answer":" add(5,4) = 9\r\n add(2,3) = 5"
   },
   {
      "q_id":"9",
      "type":"dasdsa",
      "author":"",
      "question":" adddfa",
      "answer":" asdfs"
   },
   {
      "q_id":"10",
      "type":"adfafd",
      "author":"",
      "question":" dsadsf",
      "answer":" saddasf"
   },
   {
      "q_id":"11",
      "type":"adsf",
      "author":"",
      "question":" adsfs",
      "answer":" dsadsf"
   }
]
```

Is there way to get certain elements like q_id and author and put them in html attributes?

Comment: Could you explain how this data is being given to the page (as JSON or JavaScript object and perhaps via AJAX)?

Comment: II to a curl request from the server and the server responds, then I print it out using PHP and jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse your JSON into a JavaScript array using the command `JSON.parse('{JSON HERE}')` and you could do a for loop of your array and create an HTML element for them like so:

```
$.each(arrayVar, function(i, obj) {
    $element = $('<div></div>');
    $element.attr('id') = obj['q_id'];
    $('body').append($element);
});
```

I hope this is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This is a json string, it is very easy to parse this into an array using php.

```
$DataArray =  json_decode($MyDatabaseString,True);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
                 $results = //db result
                  foreach($results as $result){
                   echo $result['q_id'];
                 }
```

Check http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp
Array => key => value

```
               // if its json

                 $results = json_decode(dbresult);
                  foreach($results as $result){
                   echo $result['q_id'];
                 }
```

Comment: You should probably find a better source than W3Schools.

Comment: they not greatest but they have the basics down, whats wrong with it?

Comment: As this is a website to ask questions (not to learn programming), I would suggest using something like the Mozilla Web API.